# Node / Pug / Jade Interpolate into variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've got a whole bunch of data being passed to a view in a Node App, and a bunch of it relates to budgets, specifically quote vs. actual.

The variables are all named similarly, like this

```
s_budget_quote_labour = 500
s_budget_actual_labour = 400
s_budget_quote_food = 1000
s_budget_actual_food= 1100
```

I want to create a custom array in my Pug template, that consists of all the cost "types" and then iterate over them, piping the cost type into the variable name. Basically something like this:

```
    - expenseArray = ['Food', 'Labor']
    - each expense, i in expenseArray
      - var expense_budget = 'info.s_budget_' + expense  
      - var expense_actual = 'info.s_actual_' + expense  
      tr
        td ${expense}
        td ${expense_budget}
        td ${expense_actual}
```

The idea being that it will loop over all of the items in my array, and pull together the proper html to build my table of expenses. I've tried piping it directly into the td a couple different ways too, but no luck. Samples...

```
td #{info.s_actual_${expense}}
td !{info.s_actual_${expense}}
```

And a few other variants... all without luck. Any idea if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) should let you get variables with dynamic names. And you can use [`.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to make the case match:

```js
- expenseArray = ['Food', 'Labor']
- each expense, i in expenseArray
  - var expense_budget = eval('info.s_budget_' + expense.toLowerCase())
  - var expense_actual = eval('info.s_actual_' + expense.toLowerCase())
  tr
    td ${expense}
    td ${expense_budget}
    td ${expense_actual}
```

However, `eval` could cause **security problems** if users can specify the value of `expenseArray`. Those users could cause arbitrary JavaScript to be run for anyone who visits that page. This solution would also need more code if you needed it to support spaces or special characters in the names of expense types. So I don't recommend this.

**Instead,** you should change the format of the `info` variable that is sent to your view. Make it so an object or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is sent instead of multiple variables with a special naming scheme. For example, `info` could be this:

```js
var info = {
  'Labour': {quote: 500, actual: 400},
  'Food': {quote: 1000, actual: 1100},
}
```

And then your template would be this:

```js
- expenseArray = ['Food', 'Labor']
- each expense, i in expenseArray
  - var expense_budget = info[expense].quote
  - var expense_actual = info[expense].actual
  tr
    td ${expense}
    td ${expense_budget}
    td ${expense_actual}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'd tried eval with no success, but I think my code was a bit different than yours so I'll try it again. I'd love to edit the object structure, but it's part of a big json result that comes out of SalesForce, so I can't control how the object is exported. That's why I was creating the array first, so I could loop through the relevant object keys. Thanks for the help though.